# Newb_Python_Checking if a process is running. Seeed XIAO RP2040

Tags: micropython

Im very new to micro controllers and I recently bought one powered via a Seeed XIAO RP2040 (ANAVI knob 3). I was wondering if there was a way to make the functions of any key dependent to the program running in Python? (eg. when chrome is running the keys will have F1, F2, F3. And when other program is open, F4,F5,F6)
I have tried os, subprocess, win32 python modules but due to the memory limitation I cannot do much.
Any suggestions?
Thank you very much!
Jose